# Auto run macro in excel when "Disable all macros with notification"

Tags: excel

In Macro Setting,  I have chosen "Disable all macros with notification" but when i open file, macro still run. I use office 2013.Can anyone help me with this issue?

Comment: This is better suited for [su]

Answer (score 1):

1.) sometimes (if you have a certain group policy applied or add-in installed) settings change if you reboot your system. Check first if "disable all macros with notification" is still selected.

2.) read about the setting to make sure it is what you intend it to be ->
 [here](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/Enable-or-disable-macros-in-Office-files-12b036fd-d140-4e74-b45e-16fed1a7e5c6/)

3.) Check if the file has a digital signature by opening the VBA editor: open workbook -> press ALT + F11 -> select Tools -> select Digital Signature.
If it does have a signature simply remove it.

Cheers

Comment: I tried it but it still runs. I think it is because I have some protected sheets.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to handle it

http://smallbusiness.chron.com/open-excel-macros-disabled-28054.html

Disable all Trusted Locations, Trust Trusted Document,Add-ins